# Exclude specific laravel route from htaccess password protection

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I protect laravel app with htaccess password protection.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I want to exclude only 1 url (laravel route) from htaccess password protection. SetEnvIf not working for non physical path.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable authentication for a specific URL by wrapping [`AuthType None`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype) inside a [`Location`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) directive

```
<Location /this/laravel/route>
    AuthType None
</Location>
```

Note however, that `Location` is not available in `.htaccess`, but only in server or virtual host configuration

> Context:   server config, virtual host

---

If this is not a dynamic route, but a URL served from the file system, you should rather use a [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) and/or [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) directive.

Comment: what exact path i need to use corresponding to "/this/laravel/route" in laravel way?

Comment: @jitendrakothiyal It is the path from the URL you enter in your browser. So, if you enter `http://example.com/some/app/public` in the browser's bar, the path should be `/some/app/public`.